# Remove blanks in import range of multiple arrays

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I have an importrange formula as below which references multiple ranges, calling the sheet URL's using the **'L Links'!Bx**, reference, each 'book' having an identical sheet set. (There are actually 90 URL's but I have only shown part here.) It works fine, except, it brings back all the blank rows, and the ranges vary in length.

Is there a simple way of removing the blank rows in the formula en masse?

`={importrange('L Links'!B3,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B4,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B5,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B6,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B7,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B8,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H")}`

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> 1. Is there a simple way of removing the blank rows in the formula en masse?

Yes, actually there are multiple ways. Try using `QUERY`.

The following example assums that the first column is not blank for the rows that the OP wants to keep:

`=QUERY(`
`{importrange('L Links'!B3,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B4,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B5,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B6,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B7,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H");importrange('L Links'!B8,"'Donor Projection Input'!A2:H")},`
`"SELECT * WHERE Col1 is not null")`

Comment: Works good- Thanks for your help!